# How to use NotificationListenerService

Tags: java, android

I dont get how to use the NotificationListenerService, could someone give the most simple example possible?

I even tried the example from [kpbird](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/07/android-notificationlistenerservice.html) but it doesnt work, could someone please explain what I need to do?

Comment: What doesn't work? Did you enable your component on the Notification listeners settings?